# Detect if a web, drop-down menu is going to display off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a CSS based simple drop down menu with multi-levels. The second or third level might go outside the visible window, with certain combinations of resolution and window size.

Some pre-built menu controls just open the drop-down to the left instead of the right, if they detect this situation.

How can I test (with JS/jQuery) for this situation?

Comment: Ron, I'm not going to write out a big answer, but make sure whatever you settle on accounts for the case where someone opens your page already scrolled down (i.e. via an anchor, or their browser "remembering" the previous position).  That being said, jQuery UI's Position utility may be what you want.  It handles 'collisions' of the type you're worried about.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if a menu item is offscreen with the following function:

```
/*---   function bIsNodeClippedOrOffscreen returns true if a node
        is offscreen (without scrolling).
        Requires jQuery.
*/
function bIsNodeClippedOrOffscreen (zJnode)
{
    var aDivPos             = zJnode.offset ();
    var iLeftPos            = aDivPos.left;
    var iTopPos             = aDivPos.top;

    var iDivWidth           = zJnode.outerWidth  (true);
    var iDivHeight          = zJnode.outerHeight (true);

    var bOffScreen          = CheckIfPointIsOffScreen (iLeftPos, iTopPos);
    var bClipped            = CheckIfPointIsOffScreen (iLeftPos + iDivWidth, iTopPos + iDivHeight);

    return (bOffScreen || bClipped);
}


function CheckIfPointIsOffScreen (iLeftPos, iTopPos)
{
    var iBrowserWidth       = $(window).width()  - 16;   //-- 16 is fudge for scrollbars, refine later
    var iBrowserHeight      = $(window).height() - 16;   //-- 16 is fudge for scrollbars, refine later
    var bOffScreen          = false;

    if (iLeftPos < 0  ||  iLeftPos >= iBrowserWidth)
        bOffScreen          = true;

    if (iTopPos < 0   ||  iTopPos >= iBrowserHeight)
        bOffScreen          = true;

    return bOffScreen;
}
```

.
Sample usage:

```
<li id="SomeMenuItem"> Get your shopping cart for free!
...
...

var Node            = $("#SomeMenuItem");

var NeedToMoveIt    = bIsNodeClippedOrOffscreen (Node);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must display the element to get the size so display the sub-menu off screen. Get the width/height of the element, calculated expected display positions (right/bottom), compare to screen width/height, decide which location to display and move element to final position.

(untested example)

```
function displaysOffPageRight(defaultLeft){
    $('#submenu1').addClass('displayOffScreen');
    var offPage = defaultLeft + $('#submenu1').width() > screen.width;
    $('#submenu1').removeClass('displayOffScreen');
    return offPage;
}
```

Comment: You could also change the display of the element in jQuery, grab its height, then set it back to hidden.  This should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When the menu is not yet displayed, you can't get its dimensions. to set its position. If you set CSS `visibility: hidden` and `display: none`, the menu will not be shown but it *will* have its dimensions defined. Then you can get it's position using `jQuery.offset` and its height/width with `jQuery.outerWidth/outerHeight` (pay attention to the `margin` options for the latter functions). Oh, and be careful if you are using any negative margins, this would require special handling.

Get the window's dimensions with `jQuery(window).height()` and `.width()` and you should be able to figure out the math from there.